# Laravel Homestead error on chown

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

i tried to install homestead but when i run

```
 vagrant up
```

at the middle i got this error
[image]

My folder structure is

```
c:/Hashicorp/vagrant
```

and the homestead at

```
c:/Homestead
```

I've added this line on my vagrantfile inside homestead:

```
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

but still no luck.

Virtual box version: 5.0
Vagrant version : 1.7.3

What should i do to make it running?

Comment: Could you please copy and paste `vagrant up` output as a text block. It would be easier to read and easier to find the question later

Comment: Why do you run `vagrant` instead of `homestead`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I want to up to VM. So i can access it. Any homestead command so i can access it? @alik

Comment: If you've installed Homestead and want to bring it up then you should issue `homestead up`. Right now I am not sure if it is a simple proxy over `vagrant` or no.

Comment: @alik i following laravel tutorial at their website. The step is using vagrant up.

Comment: I ran into the same trouble after upgrading VirtualBox to version 5.0 and Vagrant to version 1.7.3 while keeping laravel/homestead v0.2.6 (yet a new version is available). Rolling back VirtualBox  to version 4.3.8 fixed it.